# Microsoft Indic Language Input Tool for Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, input-languages

I used to use the [Microsoft Indic Language Input tool](http://www.bhashaindia.com/ilit/Kannada.aspx) with Windows 7. However, it appears that this tool is not compatible with Windows 8. Does anyone know any of the following:

1. Is it possible to make this tool work with Windows 8?
2. If the answer to 1 above is no, does Windows 8 have a built-in *equivalent* tool for typing in Indic scripts?

Comment: "it appears that this tool is not compatible with Windows 8" Did you actually try to use it?  What happened when you tried?

Comment: Have you tried running the tool?

Comment: http://www.techntrix.com/use-microsoft-indic-language-on-windows-8/

Comment: @techie007 and Ramhound, when I go to the download page for the software, I get a message saying that this software is compatible with only Windows 7, Windows Vista, and Windows XP SP2.

Comment: Ok, so if you download it and try it anyways, what happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is only the Indic 2 that is not supported in Windows 8. For Windows 8 and later, they released Indic 3, which you can download here.

http://www.bhashaindia.com/Downloads/Pages/home.aspx

Scroll down and download the Indic 3. Hope this helps.